# about class design considerations for a code segment

Tags: java

With respect to the following code segment, why does the definition of  method `read` has a `MyWritable`, while other two methods `write` and `readFields` do not have? Besides, why `read` should be defined as static? How to understand this design?

```
public class MyWritable implements Writable {
   // Some data     
   private int counter;
   private long timestamp;

   public void write(DataOutput out) throws IOException {
     out.writeInt(counter);
     out.writeLong(timestamp);
   }

   public void readFields(DataInput in) throws IOException {
     counter = in.readInt();
     timestamp = in.readLong();
   }

   public static MyWritable read(DataInput in) throws IOException {
     MyWritable w = new MyWritable();
     w.readFields(in);
     return w;
   }
 }
```

Comment: Huh?  If `read` returned `void`, then what use would it be?

Comment: It's static because it doesn't use or change `counter` or `timestamp`.

Comment: @DavidRobinson Meh; it's static because it's a factory/convenience method--and it *does* change those fields, just not directly.

Comment: @DavidRobinson Not sure that's quite right...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is very simple.

The `static` read method allows you to call the method on the actual class and return an instance. So, instead of doing:

```
MyWritable writer = new MyWritable();
writer.readFields(input);
```

You can just do:

```
MyWritable writer = MyWritable.read(input);
```

And achieve the same result. It's for convenience.

Then, it returns a `MyWritable` because otherwise you'd never get the object! The first method can return `void` because you have *already created* an object instance, but in the latter, it has to return the instance it creates for you.

Answer (score 1):

This design implements a very simple [*factory method pattern*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern): the users would call `read`, rather than calling `new MyWritable()` followed by `readFields()`.

To complete the factory method pattern implementation, make the constructor `private`, and return the constructed object by interface:

```
private MyWritable() {} // Disallow external instantiations

// Use the Writable interface rather than MyWritable as the return type
public static Writable read(DataInput in) throws IOException {
    MyWritable w = new MyWritable();
    w.readFields(in);
    return w;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Effectively, it looks as though they are trying to create a simple entry point for reading these items instead of 'new' ing up the unknown writable.  So:
MyWritable.read(dataInput);

which creates an instance in memory of MyWritable (lets call it myWritable1).  So then they invoke 'myWritable1.readFields' and allow it to 'read' and 'populate' itself.

MyWritable.read(dataInput) will RETURN myWritable1 (created above).

The static read method is completely unnecessary and probably not even a good idea. It makes it easy to use, but it's not really saving much work.
new MyWritable().readFields(dataInput) would work just as well.

Answer (score 0):

- It returns a `MyWritable` so you can do stuff with it after you read, like look at the data.
- It's static because it's a factory/convenience method.
- The others don't because you'd already have an instance if you were calling instance methods.

Answer (score 0):

In this case the `read(DataInput)` method is a factory method that creates a `MyWritable` based on some data.  It has a return type because it returns the object it creates.  It is static because a non-static factory method does not make much sense (how would you call a method on an object which has not yet been created?)